# R adding values to a column

Tags: r

So what I want to do is add a value to a column depending on the value of another column

```
+--------------------------+----------------
| ID         |   name      |    value
| 1          |   jim       |      
| 1          |   jim       |      
| 1          |   Ron       |      
| 2          |   jim       |      
| 2          |   Tim       |      
| 1          |   jim       |
```

As you can see I have this value column and I want the value to be 0 if the name is jim and 1 if the name is anything else.

```
+--------------------------+----------------
| ID         |   name      |    value
| 1          |   jim       |      0
| 1          |   jim       |      0
| 1          |   Ron       |      1
| 2          |   jim       |      0
| 2          |   Tim       |      1
| 1          |   jim       |      0
```

Anything help is appreciated , Thanks

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Not much, I'm new to R and I'm stuck

Comment: Take a look at the `ifelse` function.

Comment: @G5W okay i tried this:    
    ifelse(df$name == "jim", df$value =="0", df$value == "1") but that didn't work..it doesn't even create the new value column

Comment: Close.  But at least in your question, "jim" is not a mode, but rather a name.  You need `df$name`

Comment: Sorry, actually did name..see edits

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi thank you that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to this question was to simply do:

```
df$value <- as.integer(df$name != 'Jim')
```

Comment: haha thanks to @李哲源ZheyuanLi